# How to use table alias in codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

I'm  trying to join religions and citizen tables inside the CitizenModel. The problem is the from statement always includes the table citizen.

Here's the sample Model script:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use CodeIgniter\Model;

class CitizenModel extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'citizen';
  protected $primaryKey = 'CitizenID';
  protected $allowedFields = [
    'CitizenID',
    'ReligionId',
    ];
    
  public function getCitizen()
  {
    //$this->distinct();
    $this->select('a.*, b.Name as Religion');
    $this->from("citizen a");
    $this->join('religions b', 'b.ReligionId = a.ReligionId', 'LEFT');

    $result = $this->findAll();
    echo $this->db->getLastQuery();
    return $result;
  }
}
```

Here is the lastQuery result:

```
SELECT `a`.*, `b`.`Name` as `Religion`
FROM (`citizen`, `citizen` `a`)
LEFT JOIN `religions` `b` ON `b`.`ReligionId` = `a`.`ReligionId`
```

I tested the query in sqlyog but query result for

```
FROM (`citizen`, `citizen` `a`)
```

is different from

```
FROM (`citizen` `a`)
```

Unless I added the DISTINCT in the select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this happens because you're actually setting two selects. One in the $table property and one in your $this->from method.

What I would try to do in this case was remove the $this->from and re-write the $table property. Something like this:

```
  public function getCitizen()
  {
    //$this->distinct();
    $this->select('a.*, b.Name as Religion');
    $this->table("citizen a");
    $this->join('religions b', 'b.ReligionId = a.ReligionId', 'LEFT');

    $result = $this->findAll();
    echo $this->db->getLastQuery();
    return $result;
  }
```

If that does not work you might want to use a different database instance for that query instead of the one being use by the model. Using the query builder.

```
public function getCitizen() {
    $db = \Config\Database::connect();
    $builder = $db->table('citizen a');
    $builder->select('a.*, b.Name as Religion');
    $builder->join('religions b', 'b.ReligionId = a.ReligionId', 'LEFT');
    $result = $builder->get()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: I think it doesn't work. I removed the from and added the `$this->table("citizen a");` but it returns `FROM `citizen`` only, juslt like the default.

Comment: Then you might want to use another database instance instead of the one being used by the model. I'll add that option to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset "from" statement.

Using this line you can reset the from statement

```
->from([], true)
```

and redefine like

```
->from('gk_communication_group gkcg')
```

For example

```
public function getAll(){
    $tenant = TENANT;
    return $this
        ->from([], true)
        ->from('gk_communication_group gkcg')
        ->select("
            gkcg.id, gkcg.name, gkcg.description, 
            (SELECT count(*) 
                FROM gk_communication_group_item gki 
                WHERE gki.group=gkcg.id) as count")
        ->where("gkcg.tenant", TENANT)->get()->getResult();
}
```